# Folder on HDD showing larger than it actually is

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, bittorrent, user-folders

I have a 3 TB WD Red, which I have had for around 2 years and it has been working fine, though in these last few weeks I have been experiencing weird issues with my torrent client locking up that downloads to this hard drive. Originally I reinstalled my torrent client but that didn't fix anything, checked all drivers, which were OK and ran chkdsk /f which came back as OK and no bad sectors.

I noticed today that my music folder was seemingly larger than any other folder on the drive, when I check the root folder properties it comes back as the entire folder being larger that 3.6TB which isn't possible considering the drive is only 3TB. When I check the properties of the internal files, it comes back with the correct size of 752GB. Programs like WinDirStat seem to show the data as correct but windows file explorer seems to have an issue with it.

After backing all my data up and reformatting the drive, copying over the back up of my music folder still yields the same results. Though I have found that on my other drive I had backed this particular folder up to, it is registering the folder to be a complete 103TB's on disk, which is completely incorrect. I have run antivirus software and Malwarebytes with no success.

If it is any help, the folder structure is as follows:
X:/Music/Downloading/Complete/

The properties of the Music and every other folder give me ambiguous results, unless I check all properties within the "Complete" folder.

The "Complete" folder houses 59,276 Files and 5,083 Folders which equates to roughly 706 GB on disk.

Not sure if this information will help in anyway.

I am really unsure as to what this could be, but it does seem to hinder certain programs I am trying to use.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There might be compressed files, sparse files, symlinks or hardlinks so the total size can be larger than the disk size

Comment: How would I go about resolving this, so it shows the correct values?

Comment: you can't do anything, because it's simply showing the correct value, unless the disk is corrupted (in which case you need to do a disk check). You can check the size on disk by right clicking the folder > properties and see the size on disk there if it's smaller than the drive capacity

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/wrong-calculation-of-folder-size-by-windows/2da61a1b-d2fd-472a-ae12-a17a4cc8f7e2

Issue was a bug in a previous windows build to do with character limits on file names. I have rectified the file names that were causing the issue and updated and the issue has been resolved thus far. Thanks for everyone's input!

Comment: great that you found the root cause. You can post your own answer to the question